# Spack [Scala]: Reduce a nested tuple value by key

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, rdd, reduce

Let's say I have a Spark Scala program with a RDD named `mention_rdd` that goes as follows:

```
(name, (filename, sum))
...
(Maria, (file0, 3))
(John, (file0, 1))
(Maria, (file1, 6))
(Maria, (file2, 1))
(John, (file2, 3))
...
```

Where we have the filenames and the number of occurrences for each name.

I want to reduce and find, for each name, the filename with the max occurrences. For example:

```
(name, (filename, max(sum))
...
(Maria, (file1, 6))
(John, (file2, 3))
...
```

I tried to access the `(filename,sum)` tuple of the RDD on its own, so I can reduce from there by `name` (due to an error that said i can't traverse from the `mention_rdd` because `(String,Int)` is not a `TraversableOnce` type):

```
val output = mention_rdd.flatMap(file_counts => file_counts._2.map(file_counts._2._1, file_counts._2._2))   
        .reduceByKey((a, b) => if (a > b) a else b)
```

But I got an error saying ***value map is not a member of (String, Int)***

Is this possible to do within Spark? And if so, how? Was my approach flawed from the start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just:

```
val output = mention_rdd.reduceByKey {
  case ((file1, sum1), (file2, sum2)) =>
    if (sum2 >= sum1) (file2, sum2)
    else (file1, sum1)
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it was that simple after all. It's just that any other example I stumbled upon used a flatten map and that left me puzzled.